# openpyxl - How to add an image to worksheet?

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, openpyxl, worksheet

I have already read the documentation at https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/openpyxl/latest/openpyxl.pdf, in order to understand how to add an image to a worksheet. And so, used the following code to write my test program:

```
from openpyxl.drawing.image import Image as XLIMG
from openpyxl.worksheet import Worksheet
from openpyxl import Workbook

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

img = XLIMG('example.png')

ws.add_image(img, 'A1')

wb.save("test.xlsx")
```

Actually, the code works, and reproduces an xlsx file. However when I open the file using LibreOffice Calc, I don't see any image object, but instead empty cell at 'A1'.

[image]

I'm also pretty sure that the png file is neither empty, nor corrupt.

Concerning the versions, I'm currently using **OpenPyXL 2.5.11** and **LibreOffice 6.1.3.2**.

So what I'm missing? what might cause this problem?

Comment: You're using Python 3, right? I run it with Python 2 and it properly inserted the image, however Python 3 didn't make it even with a few code changes I've tried.

Comment: @arudzinska I'm using Python 2.

Comment: Therefore the code worked for me: Python 2.7.15, openpyxl 2.5.3,  LibreOffice 6.0.6.2. Have you tried with a different image?

Comment: @arudzinska The versions we are using are different. What matter it is, the image must be shown.

Comment: @arudzinska the last version of openpyxl is not very stable, I've found a commit that fixes this issue https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/commits/3977977a46e6. Applying the commit, solved my problem.

Comment: @arudzinska The problem is caused by a bug.

Comment: There is also this LibreOffice bug that images don't show up. If you open the same Excel File in say, Google Sheets the image is perfectly visible!